# MPMoviePlayerController automatically loops play the video at iOS13 in Some devices

Tags: ios, ios13, video-player

After the release of iOS 13, there was some exception in one of our video playback interfaces.
This interface is to play video using MPMoviePlayerController.
In some cases, videos that would only be played once will now automatically loop.
At the same time, the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification is also not received.

From the feedback of users, this problem will only appear on iOS13 devices.
After testing, I found that only one iPhone11 in all iOS13 devices will have this problem, and other iOS13 devices (including another iPhone11) have no such problem.

When the problem occurred, I printed the value of the repeatMode property and found that it is still 0.
Later I tried to manually set the repeatMode to MPMovieRepeatModeNone and found that this problem still occurs.

Some additional information:
1) For some reason, I am still using Xcode10.3 (Base SDK: iOS12.4) to compile the project, so using MPMoviePlayerController does not crash directly.
2) The problematic device is the partner's test machine, so I can only remotely instruct them to test, there is no way to debug locally.

Here is the code I used to test:

```
  NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"test" ofType:@"mp4"];
  NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

  self.playerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
  [self.playerController setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit];
  [self.playerController.backgroundView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
  self.playerController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
  [self.playerController setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
  [self.playerController.view setFrame:self.view.bounds];
  self.playerController.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
  [self.view addSubview:self.playerController.view];

  self.playerController.contentURL = url;
  [self.playerController prepareToPlay];
  [self.playerController play];
```